MapBox iOS SDK -- Can layers dynamically handle tens of thousands of points
I want to dynamically display points on a map in a data-driven fashion. Namely, I want to display tens of thousands of points on a map, it should look something like this:

And these points are constantly updating (e.g., they might be location of users, may be fetched every 5 seconds). Is this possible using the iOS MapBox SDK? The documentation on data-driven styling and layers implies that it is but it's not clarified whether dynamically rending such changing data is feasible.

You should implement displaying data by CircleLayer read this topic

You should implement displaying data by CircleLayer read this article
In the article describes how you can prepare source with data and how update this source when you need. When you update source, updates visible data on the map.
